# How to fix an apparenlty missing kernel module dependency declaration?

Tags: drivers, usb, configuration, kernel-modules, dependencies

I've encountered a relatively common problem with ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter, where it was not working at all, or was working sporadically, and `dmesg` was showing errors like

```
[23552.344134] ax88179_178a 2-1:2.1 eth1: Failed to read reg index 0x0000: -32
```

Searching on-line, I've found reports of this or similar problems without satisfactory solutions or explanation.

After some debugging, it turned out that the problem is solved if `cdc_mbim` module is loaded before `ax88179_178a`. The following solves the problem until the next reboot:

```
# rmmod ax88179_178a
# modprobe cdc_mbim
# modprobe ax88179_178a  # optional
```

I've checked that `cdc_mbim` is not declared a dependency of `ax88179_178a`, neither directly, nor indirectly.

How can I make `ax88179_178a` depend on `cdc_mbim`, so that `cdc_mbim` be always loaded automatically before `ax88179_178a`?

---

*Update.*

My question seems to be a duplicate of [*Create Linux module dependency for autoloading module*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643146).

Comment: FWIW, I've reported this issue in the Fedora bugtracker: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2137098

Comment: Related discussion on Github: https://github.com/FreddyXin/ax88179_178a/issues/6#issuecomment-1161671098

Comment: Similar question: [Create Linux module dependency for autoloading module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/643146/1131)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar, but slightly cleaner strategy also involving a file in `modprobe.d/` is to use the `softdep` feature to tell `modprobe` to load `cdc_mbim` before `ax88179_178a`. In `/etc/modprobe.d/ax88179.conf`:

```
softdep ax88179_178a pre: cdc_mbim
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [a `modprobe.d` file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/modprobe.d.5.html) to configure this without changing the kernel. Create a file, named `/etc/modprobe.d/ax88179.conf`, with the following contents:

```
install ax88179_178a /sbin/modprobe cdc_mbim; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install ax88179_178a
```

This will ensure that attempts to install `ax88179_178a` result in `cdc_mbim` being loaded first, followed by `ax88179_178a`. `--ignore-install` on the second command skips this line (to avoid endless processing).